# AWS Route 53 subdomain to different ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

I currently have two different ELB apps set up. One for production and one for development. I have Route53 handing the DNS for the site. Currently I have an A record for the main site (and another for the www of the main site) and those route to the correct ELB application without a problem. I added another A record for the "dev" subdomain so it is "dev.mydomain.com" which is meant to route to the other ELB (the devlopment one) but that does not seem to be routing properly.

Here is the setup I have..

[image: my setup]

What is the correct way to do this with Route53 and ELB?

Thanks!

Comment: I created an A record for mysite.com with an alias pointing to ELB 1, an A record for www.mysite.com with an alias pointing to ELB 1, and an A record for dev.mysite.com with an alias pointing to ELB 2, all in the same hosted zone.

Comment: I need more information, please edit your question and add the steps you've taken in detail and which troubleshooting steps have you taken already. thanks.

Comment: what more information can I get you?

Comment: Are the hosts healthy in your dev ELB?

Comment: Can you ping the ELB from the dev site server? or better telnet from the dev site server to the ELB using the application port?

Comment: Also, which error do you get in the browser when you try to access dev.site.com?

Comment: I am getting a cloudflare error when I try to get into the site. We used to use cloudflare but I removed them from the equation.

Comment: I can ssh into the ELB app from the terminal using the EB SSH command..

Comment: I am unable to ping the ELB environment from the terminal. Does that suggest an app error is the culprit here? The environment is green though.

Comment: I redeployed the AWS sample app to root out app bugs and even that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: why does the A record for `dev` pointing to beanstalk ? Shouldn't it point to ELB ?

Comment: yea, i changed that. I have the subdomain pointing working now but the SSL does not for some reason as per this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/914401/route53-ssl-subdomain