# Route53 SSL Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

I have a setup where I have a top level domain hosted and the DNS is done through Route53. The SSL certificate is done through AWS certificate manager and works fine for the top level domain. It is set up as "*.mysite.com".

I registered a subdomain with Route53 and it points to the correct ELB setup but the SSL certificate is not working for the site and therefore my resources are not loading properly at all. I went as far as to register a second certificate for the subdomain but that too does not seem to work.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What error message is your client showing when trying to connect? Are you using a subdomain of mysite.com, e.g. www.example.com, or the domain apex, i.e. example.com

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am not getting anything when I try to connect. It just hangs there. (there is an https redirect in place and I am wondering if that is contributing) I was just trying to get to dev.mysite.com

Comment: This sounds like a firewall/security group issue. Do you eventually receive an error message? Have you allowed port 443 (tcp, https) and port 80 (tcp, http) ingress on your load balancer?

Comment: Yep. I have been through the security groups a dozen times to make sure I have let it all through. I don't understand it. When I curl to the https endpoint I eventually get a 408 timeout error.

Comment: The weird thing is that this was working fine before I switch the SSL certificate...what could have caused that?

Comment: OK! found out the issue. In the Beanstalk environment there is a part where you specifity the ports for the SSL vs regular HTTP connections. In there, you have to make sure that the load balancer is listening on 443 and then forwarding to 80. do not set both of them to 443!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the aws certificate manager document (https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/).

ACM removes the wildcard label (*) when generating CNAME records for wildcard names. As a result, the CNAME record generated by ACM for a wildcard name (such as *.example.com) is the same record returned for the domain name without the wildcard label (example.com).

You cannot validate all subdomains of a domain using one CNAME record because each domain name, including host names and subdomain names, must be validated separately, each with a unique CNAME record.